# Error on importing 40M+ data using neo4j-import tool

Tags: shell, neo4j

I use `neo4j-import` to import 40M nodes, bellow is my shell:

```
[luning@pinnacle bin]$ ./neo4j-import --into ../data/weibo.db --nodes:User "/data/weibo/user-header.csv,/data/weibo/users/000000_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000001_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000002_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000003_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000004_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000005_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000006_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000007_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000008_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000009_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000010_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000011_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000012_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000013_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000014_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000015_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000016_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000017_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000018_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000019_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000020_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000021_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000022_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000023_1.csv,/data/weibo/users/000024_0.csv,/data/weibo/users/000025_0.csv" --delimiter "TAB"

Nodes
[*>:87.20 MB/s---------------------------|PROPERTIES(2)===============|NOD|v:227.03 MB/s(2)====] 48MImport error: Panic called, so exiting

Neo4j Import Tool
    neo4j-import is used to create a new Neo4j database from data in CSV files. See 
    the chapter "Import Tool" in the Neo4j Manual for details on the CSV file format 
    - a special kind of header is required.
Usage:
--into <store-dir>
    Database directory to import into. Must not contain existing database.
--nodes [:Label1:Label2] "<file1>,<file2>,..."
    Node CSV header and data. Multiple files will be logically seen as one big file 
    from the perspective of the importer. The first line must contain the header. 
    Multiple data sources like these can be specified in one import, where each data 
    source has its own header. Note that file groups must be enclosed in quotation 
    marks.
--relationships [:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE] "<file1>,<file2>,..."
    Relationship CSV header and data. Multiple files will be logically seen as one 
    big file from the perspective of the importer. The first line must contain the 
    header. Multiple data sources like these can be specified in one import, where 
    each data source has its own header. Note that file groups must be enclosed in 
    quotation marks.
--delimiter <delimiter-character>
    Delimiter character, or 'TAB', between values in CSV data. The default option is 
    ,.
--array-delimiter <array-delimiter-character>
    Delimiter character, or 'TAB', between array elements within a value in CSV
```

I have checked their schema. They are all consistent. It shows

> Import error: Panic called, so exiting

Anybody knows how to solve it?

Below is my stacktrace:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Panic called, so exiting
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.StageExecution.stillExecuting(StageExecution.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.anyStillExecuting(ExecutionSupervisor.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.finishAwareSleep(ExecutionSupervisor.java:102)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.supervise(ExecutionSupervisor.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisors.superviseDynamicExecution(ExecutionSupervisors.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.executeStages(ParallelBatchImporter.java:226)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:151)
    at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Panic called, so exiting
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.AbstractStep.assertHealthy(AbstractStep.java:189)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.AbstractStep.await(AbstractStep.java:180)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutorServiceStep.receive(ExecutorServiceStep.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.AbstractStep.sendDownstream(AbstractStep.java:226)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutorServiceStep$2.call(ExecutorServiceStep.java:103)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutorServiceStep$2.call(ExecutorServiceStep.java:87)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.executor.DynamicTaskExecutor$Processor.run(DynamicTaskExecutor.java:217)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Panic called, so exiting
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Panic called, so exiting
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.InputException: ERROR in input
  data source: BufferedCharSeeker[buffer:org.neo4j.csv.reader.SectionedCharBuffer@4ac5af5c, seekPos:2764030, line:2882236]
  in field: descriptions:string:4
  for header: [id:string, screenname:string, locations:string, descriptions:string, :IGNORE, profileimageurl:string, gender:string, followerscount:string, friendscount:string, statusescount:string, favouritescount:string, verified:string, verifiedreason:string, :IGNORE, :IGNORE, :IGNORE, :IGNORE, :IGNORE, :IGNORE, :IGNORE, darenint:string, :IGNORE, :IGNORE, updateddate:string]
  raw field value: 6:19:
  original error: Tried to read in a value larger than effective buffer size 8388608
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:152)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:42)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.NestingIterator.fetchNextOrNull(NestingIterator.java:61)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.IteratorBatcherStep.nextBatchOrNull(IteratorBatcherStep.java:54)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.InputIteratorBatcherStep.nextBatchOrNull(InputIteratorBatcherStep.java:42)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep.process(ProducerStep.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep$1.run(ProducerStep.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tried to read in a value larger than effective buffer size 8388608
    at org.neo4j.csv.reader.BufferedCharSeeker.fillBufferIfWeHaveExhaustedIt(BufferedCharSeeker.java:258)
    at org.neo4j.csv.reader.BufferedCharSeeker.nextChar(BufferedCharSeeker.java:231)
    at org.neo4j.csv.reader.BufferedCharSeeker.seek(BufferedCharSeeker.java:109)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputEntityDeserializer.fetchNextOrNull(InputEntityDeserializer.java:81)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: can you run it with `--stacktrace`. Which version are you running?

Comment: I am using 2.2.0 RC01. Thanks.

Comment: can you share your input files somewhere? at least the first 50 and last 50 lines each?

Comment: would u give me your email ? @MichaelHunger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the fields probably have a quote that doesn't end that quote... and so the CSV parser will read and read until it finds the next quote. It's inlikely that you've got one field in there that's 8M big, so that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: well, in that field, I do have some char like ””“,“;”," ' ". I tried to ignore that field. but still failed. Most interestingly, I have some files. Some of them can be imported but not others.

Comment: Odd, and hard to go through all fields I can imagine. We're working on a feature where the CSV parser is able to detect these anomalies and warn about to feed back to the user about which line might be at fault.

Comment: thats great. You know i even hacked into your class by using reverse engineering tools to see what happened. But it won't help. And notifying which line goes wrong is amazing functionality.

Comment: even the neo4jimpot can't work on incremental mode. I feel so sad about it.

Comment: Incremental import is coming later on I think. At this point the import tool is deemed "fast enough" to rerun a failed import from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and removing special characters such as "*", "&","/"  BUT keeping the single quotes was enough to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also got "Import error: Executor has been shut down" and "Import error: Panic called, so exiting" errors when I tried to import data to my graph using this method.

My data was free of quote characters (" and ') when I was getting these errors.

What solved my problem was getting rid of all other special characters.

I might have missed something in the documentation because I thought all the text in my node attributes would be read in as strings. Turns out `neo4j-import` doesn't like characters like "&" and "/"!

When I edited my data (yay `sed`!) to contain only alphanumeric characters the import tool worked perfectly.